# Rails association triggers SQL where clause with 'model'.'model_id' instead of 'model'.'id'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations

In my Card model, I have the following associations :

```
has_many :sub_cards, ->(obj) { where('parent_card_id = ?', obj.id) },
           inverse_of: :parent_card, :class_name => 'Card'
belongs_to :parent_card, class_name: 'Card', optional: true
```

Whenever I try to use them, for example in the console typing `c.sub_cards`, I get the following error :

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column
>   'cards.card_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `cards`.* FROM `cards` WHERE
>   `cards`.`card_id` = 237 AND (parent_card_id = 237)

In fact, the SQL request has `'cards'.'card_id' = something`, whereas it should be `'cards'.'id' = something` if I refer to my other working associations.
The problem is I can't find where this syntax comes from.

Has somebody ever experienced this issue ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which attribute is the foreign key of the relation by passing `:foreign_key => "some_attribute_id"`. Hope this helps. Good luck!

EDIT:

Don't know if this works for you, but I would write it kinda like this:

```
has_many :sub_cards, ->(obj) { where('parent_card_id = ?', obj.id) },
       inverse_of: :parent_card, :class_name => 'Card', foreign_key: 'parent_card_id'
belongs_to :parent_card, class_name: 'Card', foreign_key: "parent_card_id", optional: true
```

I think you could give this a try, or something near it. Good luck again!

Comment: It didn't change anything, I think it is not needed because the attribute is the name of the association + _id, but thank you for your help :)

Comment: @V.Déhaye edited my answer... hope it helps and good luck bro!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help because for the belongs_to you're right but it's already like that, but for the other way, the sub_cards have to be found by looking in the parent_card_id attribute and finding the cards referring to the object calling the association, i.e. having the id of the object calling the association in this field. Still, thank you again !

Comment: try leaving what you have, just add `, foreign_key: "parent_card_id"` at the en of your `has_many`.

Comment: You are right, it works, thank you very much man ! I appreciate !